# Scanning without sequences in theano? (emulating range())

Tags: python, loops, iteration, theano

Theano newbie here. I am doing some experiments in order to generate variable length sequences. I started with the simplest thing coming to my mind: emulating range(). Here is the simple code I wrote:

```
from theano import scan
from theano import function
from theano import tensor as  T

X = T.iscalar('X')
STEP = T.iscalar('STEP')
MAX_LENGTH = 1024  # or any othe very large value

def fstep(i, x, t):
    n = i * t
    return n, until(n >= x)

t_fwd_range, _ = scan(
    fn=fstep,
    sequences=T.arange(MAX_LENGTH),
    non_sequences=[X, STEP]
)

getRange = function(
    inputs=[X, Param(STEP, 1, 'step')],
    outputs=t_fwd_range
)

getRange(x, step)
print list(f)
assert list(f[:-1]) == list(range(0, x, step))
```

So I had to use `MAX_LENGTH` as the length of a range to be used as input of the `fstep` theano `scan`. So, my main question is this: is there any way to use a `scan` without an input sequence? And, as I suppose the answer is *no*, the next question is: is this the correct (most efficient, ecc) way to do what I am traying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to provide an input sequence to scan. You can instead specify the number of iterations via scan's `n_steps` parameter. Optionally, you can also specify a condition under which the scan should stop early via `theano.scan_module.until`.

So Python's `range` function can be emulated using Theano's `scan` without specifying an input sequence by figuring out how many iterations would be required to construct the requested sequence.

Here's an implementation of the range function based on Theano's `scan`. The only complicated part is figuring out how many steps are required.

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.ifelse


def scan_range_step(x_tm1, step):
    return x_tm1 + step


def compile_theano_range():
    tt.arange
    symbolic_start = tt.lscalar()
    symbolic_stop = tt.lscalar()
    symbolic_step = tt.lscalar()
    n_steps = tt.cast(
        tt.ceil(tt.abs_(symbolic_stop - symbolic_start) / tt.cast(tt.abs_(symbolic_step), theano.config.floatX)),
        'int64') - 1
    outputs, _ = theano.scan(scan_range_step, outputs_info=[symbolic_start], n_steps=n_steps,
                             non_sequences=[symbolic_step], strict=True)
    outputs = theano.ifelse.ifelse(tt.eq(n_steps, 0), tt.stack(symbolic_start), outputs)
    f = theano.function([symbolic_start, symbolic_stop, symbolic_step],
                        outputs=tt.concatenate([[symbolic_start], outputs]))

    def theano_range(start, stop=None, step=1):
        assert isinstance(start, int)
        assert isinstance(step, int)
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError()
        if stop is None:
            stop = start
            start = 0
        else:
            assert isinstance(stop, int)
        if start == stop:
            return []
        if stop < start and step > 0:
            return []
        if stop > start and step < 0:
            return []
        return f(start, stop, step)

    return theano_range


def main():
    theano_range = compile_theano_range()
    python_range = range

    for start in [-10, -5, -1, 0, 1, 5, 10]:
        for stop in [-10, -5, -1, 0, 1, 5, 10]:
            for step in [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]:
                a = theano_range(start, stop, step)
                b = python_range(start, stop, step)
                assert numpy.all(numpy.equal(a, b)), (start, stop, step, a, b)


main()
```

Clearly this is a daft thing to do/use for real since Theano already provides a symbolic version of Python's `range` function, i.e. `theano.tensor.arange`. The built in implementation is also far more efficient than our `scan` version because it doesn't use `scan`, it uses a custom operation instead.

As a rule of thumb: you *have to* set a maximum number of iteration steps via the `range` or the the `n_steps` argument. You can set it to a very large number and then use `theano.scan_module.until` to stop the iteration at an earlier stage if your stop condition is met.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. Even if not declaring explicitly a range, I still have to fix a certain number of step, so I assume there is no way to implement a sort of a `while` loop. I assume that it is for some sort of optimization: am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does seem as if you one must specify either an input sequence or a number of steps. It doesn't seem possible to rely on only the `until` condition. However, there may be no disadvantage to specifying a very large `n_steps` and using an `until` condition to stop early.